# Get Gif in UIImageView from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

[GIFU](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Gifu) library using to display a Gif image in `UIImageView` picked from `UIImagePickerController`

```
  public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    
    
    let imageUrl          = info[.referenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = info[.originalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)
    
    do {
      try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
    catch
    {
      // Catch exception here and act accordingly
    }
    self.pickerController(picker, didSelect: data)
  }
  
  func didSelect(image: Data?) {
    
    tempImage.prepareForAnimation(withGIFData: image!, loopCount: 3) {
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
        self.tempImage.startAnimating()
      })
    }
  }
```

Image displaying but not animating, looks image format gets changed after selecting.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting GIF to jpeg data using the following line of code.

```
 let data  = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)
```

Avoid data conversion to JPEG, now(I guess from iOS 13 onwards) native controller does have support for previewing gif file on selection try that.